# Streaming a file using hackney

Tags: erlang, streaming, elixir, multipart

I'm trying to stream a multipart form using hackney.

This is my current code:

```
method = :post
path = "https://httpbin.org/post"
req_headers = [
  {"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"}
]

{:ok, pid} = :hackney.request(method, path, req_headers, :stream, [])

:hackney.send_multipart_body(pid, {:file, "/Users/gmile/.vimrc"})

{:ok, _status, _headers, pid} = :hackney.start_response(pid)

{:ok, body} = :hackney.body(pid)
```

On line with `:hackney.send_multipart_body/2`, I see get exception:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.byte_size(nil)
    (hackney) src/hackney_multipart.erl:134: :hackney_multipart.mp_header/2
    (hackney) src/hackney_multipart.erl:239: :hackney_multipart.mp_file_header/2
    (hackney) src/hackney_request.erl:222: :hackney_request.stream_multipart/2
    (hackney) src/hackney.erl:432: anonymous fn/2 in :hackney.send_multipart_body/2
    read_and_stream.exs:13: (file)
```

Question: **what am I doing wrong?**

There's clearly a bug in my code, but since there's little documentation about `:hackney.send_multipart_body/2` I can't wrap my head around this.

---

I started debugging.

Here's the execution path from the stacktrace, in the call order:

1. https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/master/src/hackney.erl#L432
2. https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/master/src/hackney_request.erl#L222
3. https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/master/src/hackney_multipart.erl#L239
4. https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/master/src/hackney_multipart.erl#L134

If I understand correctly, there should a `Boundary` variable set in the HTTP client process. However I can't seem to understand where it is being set.

Comment: I think you need to use `:stream_multipart` as the 4th argument (instead of `:stream`) in the call to `:hackney.request/5`.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. You just saved me a few hours of scratching my head :) Please post the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `:hackney.send_multipart_body/2`, your request's body (fourth argument) should be `:stream_multipart`, not `:stream`:

```
{:ok, pid} = :hackney.request(method, path, req_headers, :stream_multipart, [])
```