# Can't upload pdf to slack "no_file_data" with Elixir and Hackney

Tags: http, elixir, slack, slack-api

I'm writing a slack bot in Elixir that has to upload a pdf to a channel.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
    {:ok, ref} = :hackney.request(
      :post,
      "https://slack.com/api/files.upload?"
      <> Plug.Conn.Query.encode(%{
          "channels" => channel_id,
          "filename" => "test.pdf",
          "filetype" => "pdf"
        }),
      [
        {"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"},
        {"Authorization", "Bearer xoxb-XXXXX"},
      ],
      :stream_multipart,
      [])

    :hackney.send_multipart_body(
      ref,
      {:file, "./test.pdf"})

    {:ok, _status, _headers, ref} = :hackney.start_response(ref)

    {:ok, body} = :hackney.body(ref)

    body |> Poison.decode! |> IO.inspect
```

But I get this error:
`%{"error" => "no_file_data", "ok" => false}`

I've used this question as a basis: [Streaming a file using hackney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616530/streaming-a-file-using-hackney)

Version:

- Elixir: 1.10.2
- OTP: 22.0.7
- Hackney: 1.15
- PLug: 1.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I Just needed to remove `{"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"}` in the header of the request. Hackney already provides one with a **boundary**.

My `Content-Type` Looked like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

When it should have looked like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------tlzhgtmgeelwolfm
```

Here is the corrected code:

```
    {:ok, ref} = :hackney.request(
      :post,
      "https://slack.com/api/files.upload?"
      <> Plug.Conn.Query.encode(%{
          "channels" => channel_id,
          "filename" => "test.pdf",
          "filetype" => "pdf"
        }),
      [
        {"Authorization", "Bearer xoxb-XXXXX"},
      ],
      :stream_multipart,
      [])

    :hackney.send_multipart_body(
      ref,
      {:file, "./test.pdf"})

    {:ok, _status, _headers, ref} = :hackney.start_response(ref)

    {:ok, body} = :hackney.body(ref)

    body |> Poison.decode! |> IO.inspect
```